# sentences contain the exactly word in python

Tags: python, pandas, cpu-word

I want to return the sentences that contain the exactly words in the searchfor list

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Test 1012/UOI.xlsx')
a = df['Content']
searchfor =['hot' ,'yes'  and 200 more words in it]
b = a[a.str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]
print(b)
```

for example:

```
Content = ['the photo is good','nice picture'...]
```

The result should not print any sentences,however, 'photo' contains the word 'hot', the result gives me 'the photo is good'. So anyone know how to solve this problem? I only want to get the result exactly contains the words in the searchfor list.

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundary which are added for each value of `searchfor`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Content':['the photo is good','nice picture']})
print (df)
             Content
0  the photo is good
1       nice picture

searchfor =['hot','yes','nice']
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in searchfor)


b = df.loc[df['Content'].str.contains(pat), 'Content']
#your solution
#b = a[a.str.contains(pat)]
print (b)
1    nice picture
Name: Content, dtype: object
```